# docker-compose context references directories that are not related

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I made two files like this:

```
# file: /home/john/work/docker/build.yml


version: "3.8"
services:
  website:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/docker-files/build.dockerfile
    entrypoint: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

```
# file: /home/john/work/docker/docker-files/build.dockerfile
FROM mysql:latest
```

Then I ran the following commands:

```
cd /home/john/work/docker
docker-compose -f build.yml up --build -d
```

But this gave the error

```
error checking context: 'no permission to read from '/home/john/work/db/docker-john/mongo/WiredTiger''.
```

I don't understand why the error mentions `/home/john/work/db/docker-john/mongo/WiredTiger`?  It's not even related to my docker project and I make no mention of it!  If I delete the directory `/home/john/work/db`, then my `docker-compose -f build.yml up --build -d` works perfectly.

What's going on? Why is `docker-compose` referencing directories that have nothing to do with what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (first) Compose file mentioned with a `docker-compose -f` option is in `/home/john/work/docker`, so all paths in all Compose files are considered relative to this directory.

When you build the image, you specify its parent as the build context:

```yaml
build:
  context: ../
```

Relative to the Compose file's directory, this is the `/home/john/work` directory.

Docker sends itself a copy of everything in the context directory, less what's in that directory's [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).  If a subdirectory of that is unreadable then you'll get the sort of error you describe.

I'm guessing you don't actually mean to copy the parent directory into the image, and you need to change

```yaml
build:
  context: .
```

Double-check file paths in the Dockerfile: the left-hand side of any `COPY` (and `ADD`) directives is always relative to this `context:` directory (with leading `..` and leading `/` removed).

Consider naming the Dockerfile exactly `Dockerfile` and putting it in the top-level directory of the project to simplify this further.  If this build fragment is only used on developer systems but is always used there, you can also name the file `docker-compose.override.yml` and [Compose will automatically use that](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) as well.

```yaml
# docker-compose.override.yml
# (only for development, not for production)
version: '3.8'
services:
  website:
    build: .
```

Comment: Perfect timing....just a few minutes ago, I noticed that if I do `chown -R john:john /home/john/work/db`, then my error goes away.  But if I change thigns back to `chown -R systemd-coredump:systemd-coredump /home/john/work/db`, then I get the error again. My next question would have been why the `systemd-coredump` user is related to any of this.  Your answer basically answered my prospective new question as well.